# Cartesian Product with user input

Tags: python-3.x, cartesian-product

I need to write a program for a user to be able to input 2-10 numbers and create a cartesian product. This is what i have so far but line 39 is saying "int" object is not callable. I need help making this work.

```
print("list")


firstList=[1,4]
secondList=[2,5,6]
cartesianProduct=0

print=(input("Enter first set of numbers: "))
print=(input("Enter second set of numbers: "))

def CartesianProduct(firstList, secondList):

if len(firstList):
  return None

if len(secondList):
  return None

product=[ ]
for elementA in firstList:
 for elementB in secondList:
   product.append([elementA,elementB])

return product


print(cartesianProduct([firstList], [secondList]))    ##This is line 39

print("End Program")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you sure the code is correctly indented? it seems its not. Also, could you include the full traceback of the error?

Comment: `cartesianProduct` is not a function but rather an integer. From the program above, it is defined as being equal to zero. How do you then want to use it as a function?

Answer (score -1):

> `print(cartesianProduct([firstList], [secondList]))`

`cartesianProduct` is an unused variable defined before the `input`'s. The function is called `CartesianProduct`.

Also, Python uses snake_case by convention, so the function name should be `cartesian_product`.

Comment: I changed it and it went to say cartesian_product is not defined

Comment: Did you change both occurences?